# IBOutletCollection of UIButtons is empty after viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uibutton, iboutletcollection

As said in the title, my IBOutletCollection of UIButtons is empty after viewDidLoad.
I created a IBOutletCollection of UILabels the same way, and this one is working perfectly.
Any idea how this can be fixed, or where i made a mistake?

Here is the Code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *lbl_save;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *lbl_cancel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *lbl_edit;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *btn_changeData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *btn_save;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *btn_cancel;
```

The buttons are placed in a xib and linked correctly to the corresponding outlets. Just like the labels.
[image: Outlets linked]

The time i press the one of the Buttons is the first time, i want to access the Buttons in Code.

```
for (UIButton *btn in _btn_changeData) {
    btn.hidden = NO;
    btn.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
for (UIButton *btn in _btn_save) {
    btn.hidden = YES;
    btn.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
for (UIButton *btn in _btn_cancel) {
    btn.hidden = YES;
    btn.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
for (UILabel *lbl in _lbl_save) {
    lbl.hidden = YES;
}
for (UILabel *lbl in _lbl_cancel) {
    lbl.hidden = YES;
}
for (UILabel *lbl in _lbl_edit) {
    lbl.hidden = NO;
}
```

That is also where i got the following Exception and realized, that my Button OUtletcollection is empty.

> -[UIButton countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa8a8850
>   [image]

I neither overwrite the outletcollection, nor do i change attributes of the buttons.
Its just that the labels are there in the collection and the buttons not. And i have no idea why.

Thx in advance for any help.

Mav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea that comes to my mind is that the properties are not correctly synthesized. Is `_btn_changeData` really the ivar behind `btn_changeData` property?

Second idea is something I saw while debugging someone else's code. When outlets are incorrectly connected, for example, if the controller references itself, two controller instances can be create. Obviously only of of them will have the outlets connected. Make sure only of instance is created.

For debugging, implementing the setter by yourself might be a good idea.

Edit:
After rereading, the problem is actually different they you say in your question. The error message `-[UIButton countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa8a8850`

doesn't mean that `_btn_changeData` is an empty array. It means there is a `UIButton` instead of an array.
Having said this, you should check if you are not overwriting the data in `_btn_changeData` somewhere.

Comment: Since I'm using xcode 4.6 with the newest sdk i don't have any Synthesize at all. The compiler does this automatically for me.
Your ideas all sound good, but whats confusing me is, that the labels outletcollections is working fine and the buttons don't.
As you can see in the image below the exception the debugger can access the ivar _btn_changeData and it is not nil. thus it gets initialized properly but its just not filled with the buttons.

Comment: @Maverick1st Updated the answer. Note that the debugger works a bit differently from normal code. When it says there is `NSArray` inside, the `NSArray` is probably taken from the ivar declaration, not from the actual data.

Comment: That was it. I had a leftover UIButton with the same identifier in my xibs connections and this was overwriting the outletcollection.
Your answer hinted me just in the right direction.
Thx alot man. You saved me hours of thinking :)